# Attach event listeners to all items on a layer in Paper.js

Tags: javascript, event-handling, paperjs

In jQuery, I can attach an event to all elements like a paragraph, using `$("p")`. Does something similar exist for Paper.js. I tried using `project.activeLayer.children.onMouseEnter` but that did not work.

I was thinking about looping over all the children inside the `onFrame` function but that seems wrong. It will probably attach multiple event listeners to the same item. So, all items will have many event listeners attached to them but I am not sure.

What is the best way to attach event listeners to all current and future items in a project layer in Paper.js?

Link: http://paperjs.org/reference/item/#onmouseenter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to attack an event listener to the [Tool](http://paperjs.org/reference/tool/).
The `event` argument that will be passed to the listener will then have an `item` property which is the event target item.
Here is a simple [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.15/S/ZZJRS8MwEMe/ylFkq66WIghSmS/zxQdB1LdtsJjeXFyWk+S6iqPf3STdOqeBJOTun1/+l2SXGLHBpExe1shylWSJpCqsmUjnZB6pdnhPjYExpLhFw+cwvgNJxpHGXNN7F80V4wYGAziu8kA+v53ZmQldI4OqPKboQ5UVzbMwFW0mykqNaad2yA+G0W6FTv9KMrgqiuJINdjAEynDr/jF6S6EwDfvj72PEoYTreQayIAAGQnABN42KHYQHA6zw6bPwClhq7DJJQYHMIJpkcHlTTHvVR+1Y7VUUrAi4w/olMOQbo++lrWRQQD/a4TeZTQveJXvU30ilhC5ZVddbiPCb77o/Dn1jdlvuRWVql0J18VJeKm0npAmD4pTDzpRhXsoYRHf8Gw3GqmqXRzy+6LaMPjv8WZRrONNuaScztsf) demonstrating this.

```js
tool.onMouseDown = (event) => console.log(event.item && event.item.name);

let id = 0;

drawRandomCircle();
setInterval(drawRandomCircle, 2000);

new PointText({
    content: 'Click on a circle to log its name',
    point: view.center + [0, -80],
    justification: 'center'
});

function drawRandomCircle() {
    new Path.Circle({
        center: Point.random() * view.size,
        radius: 50,
        fillColor: Color.random(),
        name: `item ${++id}`
    });
}
```